HP printer EWS replace the self signed certificate with a signed certificate
I created a csr using HP printer Embedded Web Server (EWS), I tried to create a CA certificate (Comodo SSL), but I need to valid it an email like "Admin@HPICxxxxx.home" or CNAME (DNS) but EWS is on LAN (not internet), "HPICxxxxx.home" which is not a fully qualified domain  ?
Thanks
